# Why this code show syntax error in ajax script at the end of script

Tags: php, ajax

i want to try to search data from ajax, i send data and page number in ajax for calling data to particular page but its not working properly, kindly tell me a solution to do this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Member Directory</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="jquery.js"></script>

<script>



function getdata(cat,page)
         {

         if(cat.length>0)
         {

         $.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "getdetail.php",
data: "from="+cat+ "&page="+page ,
success: function(response){

$('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
$('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
 document.getElementById("show1").innerHTML = response;
    }
});

         }

         }       

$(document).ready(function(){
       $("#searchform").hide();
         $("#addvance").click(function(){
           $("#searchform").slideToggle(200);
          });


  });



  function search(page) {

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "searchform.php",
data:   "page="+ page + "&gender=" + document.getElementById('gender').value + "&gautra=" +document.getElementById('gautra').value+
         "&fname=" +document.getElementById('fname').value + "&lname=" +document.getElementById('lname').value+
         "&state=" +document.getElementById('state').value + "&city=" +document.getElementById('city').value+
         "&birth_place=" +document.getElementById('birth_place').value+ "&mobile=" +document.getElementById('mobile').value ,
success: function(response){
$('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
$('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
 document.getElementById("show1").innerHTML = response;
    }
});





});
</script>
<style type="text/css">

.DirectoryLinkTable tr td input[type=button]{
background: none;
border: none;
padding: 0px;
margin-right: 5px;
border-right: 1px solid #333;
padding-right: 5px;
cursor:pointer;
float:left;
font-size:12px;
line-height:20px;
}
.DirectoryLinkTable tr td input[type=button].AdvanceSearch, .AdvanceSearch{
    float:right;
    border:1px solid #333;
    padding:0px 3px;
    background:#feef8d;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div>
<table class="DirectoryLinkTable"><tr>
<td>
<input type="button" value="All"  class="button" >
<input type="button" value="A" onclick="getdata(this.value,'1')">
<input type="button" value="B" onclick="getdata(this.value,'1')">
<input type="button" value="C"  onclick="getdata(this.value,'1')">
<input type="button" value="D" onclick="getdata(this.value,'1')">
<input type="button" value="E" onclick="getdata(this.value,'1')">
<input type="button" value="F" onclick="getdata(this.value,'1')">
<input type="button" value="G" onclick="getdata(this.value,'1')">
<input type="button" value="H" onclick="getdata(this.value,'1')">
<input type="button" value="I" onclick="getdata(this.value,'1')">
<input type="button" value="J" onclick="getdata(this.value,'1')">
<input type="button" value="K" onclick="getdata(this.value,'1')">
<input type="button" value="L" onclick="getdata(this.value,'1')">
<input type="button" value="M" onclick="getdata(this.value,'1')">
<input type="button" value="N" onclick="getdata(this.value,'1')">
<input type="button" value="O" onclick="getdata(this.value,'1')">
<input type="button" value="P" onclick="getdata(this.value,'1')">
<input type="button" value="Q" onclick="getdata(this.value,'1')">
<input type="button" value="R" onclick="getdata(this.value,'1')">
<input type="button" value="S" onclick="getdata(this.value,'1')">
<input type="button" value="T" onclick="getdata(this.value,'1')">
<input type="button" value="U" onclick="getdata(this.value,'1')">
<input type="button" value="V" onclick="getdata(this.value,'1')">
<input type="button" value="W" onclick="getdata(this.value,'1')">
<input type="button" value="X" onclick="getdata(this.value,'1')">
<input type="button" value="Y" onclick="getdata(this.value,'1')">
<input type="button" value="Z" onclick="getdata(this.value,'1')">
<input type="button" value="Advance Search" id="addvance" class="AdvanceSearch">
</td></tr></table>
<form id="searchform"  method="post" name="form">
<table>
<tr><td>Gender</td><td><input type="text" name="gender" id="gender"></td><td>Gautra</td><td><select name="gautra" id="gautra" >
                        <option value="">-Select Gautra-</option> 
                        <option value="Sonigra">Sonigra</option>
                        <option value="Devda">Devda</option>
                        <option value="Jodha">Jodha</option>
                        <option value="Ranawat">Ranawat</option>
                        <option value="dulawat">Dulawat</option>
                        </select></td></tr>
<tr><td>First Name</td><td><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"></td><td>Last Name</td><td><input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"></td></tr>
<tr><td>State</td><td><input type="text" name="state" id="state" ></td><td>City</td><td><input type="text" name="city" id="city"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Birth Place</td><td><input type="text" name="birth_place" id="birth_place"></td><td>Mobile Num.</td><td><input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile"></td></tr>
<tr><td height="26"><input type="button" value="search" id="" class="AdvanceSearch button" onclick="search('1')" ></td></tr>

</table>
</form>
</div>


<div id="show1">

</div>
<div>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Replace the `});` with `}` in the last line.

Comment: but its not working properly WHAT?

Comment: Let us know what error your getting  specificly?

Comment: Instead of having all those `onclick` attributes, you should use jquery's event binding techniques: `$('.DirectoryLinkTable :button').click(getData)` also it's 2013 and we still use HTML tables for layouts?